# Monadic traversal with UUAGC

Tags: haskell, tree-traversal, uuagc

I'd like to write a tree traversal with UUAGC where attributes are computed in a particular fixed monad (for example's sake, let's say I want to annotate each node with a fresh `IORef ()`). Is there a way to do that with UUAGC? (For simplicity's sake, let's further suppose that my traversal can be statically scheduled).

I see that `uuagc` has a `--monadic` flag:

```
--monadic     Experimental: generate monadic code
```

but that seems to generate syntactically invalid Haskell code; for example, given

```
imports {
import Data.IORef
}

data Tree
   | X

attr Tree
   syn iden :: {IORef ()}

sem Tree
  | X lhs.iden = newIORef ()


{
main :: IO ()
main = do
  r <- sem_Tree X
  print =<< readIORef r
}
```

the generated code is a nonsensical mess of pure and monadic bindings:

```
sem_Tree_X =
    (let _lhsOiden :: (IORef ())
         _lhsOiden <- ({-# LINE 12 "monad.ag" #-}
                       newIORef ()
                       {-# LINE 39 "monad.hs" #-}
                       )
     in  ( _lhsOiden))
```